# Модное нынче приветствие "добрый"

Tags: грамотная-речь, сокращения, этикет

Сейчас стало нередким не только услышать в ответ на *"Добрый день/вечер!"* просто слово *"Добрый!"* (что ещё, на мой взгляд, допустимо), но и его же в качестве ***первого приветствия.***

*Что вы об этом думаете?* Мне кажется, в этом проявляется неуважение к собеседнику или к нормальному языку как таковому. Например, если кто-то лебезит перед начальником, он не придёт к нему со словами "Добрый, Александр Сергеевич!" Да и даже если примерно одинаково себя со всеми ведёт и не переживает, что о нём подумают, вряд ли ему так скажет.

Answer (score 1):

> Что вы об этом думаете?

Да ничего не думаю. Этикет вообще трудно комментировать не впадая в субъективность. Скажем так, явного неуважения к приветствуемому я тут не вижу, а остальное - сфера быстроменяющихся этикетных правил. Конечно, все сильно зависит от контекста.
Ваш пример с "Александром Сергеевичем" - безусловно не образец хорошего тона. Но ошибка тут не этикетная, а стилистическая. Такое приветствие явно не для выспренного разговора, что-то вроде сказанного на бегу "привет!". Конечно, использование его при величании по имени-отчеству вызывает в лучшем случае усмешку.
Не знаю пока, что и добавить...

Comment: Спасибо! Нет-нет, конечно, стилистическая, я и не считал её этикетной. "Этикет" только меткой затронул, поскольку решил, что хоть какое-то отношение к этикету мой вопрос имеет.

Answer (score 1):

А эта форма действительно так часто употребляется? Я не припомню ни разу, чтобы кто-то здоровался со мной первым, используя только слово "добрый".

Но даже если и так, то это наверняка форма, используемая в неофициальных, неформальных отношениях. И тут хочу отметить вашу формулировку "неуважение к собеседнику". Я часто замечаю, что люди употребляют антоним в комплементарном значении: весь мир делится на уважение и неуважение. Такой подход, на мой взгляд, теряет нейтральную позицию, а она есть.

Если кто-то использует слово "привет" или "добрый" в качестве приветствия, то это не проявление неуважения, а *не проявление уважения*. Я считаю, что тут нет ничего плохого или постыдного: если кто-то использует такое приветствие, это говорит лишь о том, что в ваших отношениях не требуется постоянного проявления уважения в каждой мелочи. Вы и так прекрасно знаете, как вы друг к другу относитесь, и цените краткость коммуникации больше, чем постоянный официоз и напоминания о взаимном уважении.

Хочу также упомянуть, что на своём опыте я замечаю немного другое преобразование приветствия "Добрый день!".

Сама фраза "Добрый день!" очень формальна и для многих людей, сдается, практически лишена смысла. Ситуация, на мой взгляд, аналогична "Здравствуйте!": да, чисто теоретически, фразы имеют какой-то смысл (пожелания добра/здоровья), но многие произносят их, не вкладывая никаких посылов кроме приветственного подтверждения "я вижу тебя".

Поэтому, когда тот или иной говорящий пытается вдохнуть в приветствие немного жизни, вернуть немного того самого смысла, это сильно выделяется из общей массы приветствий. И я на своем опыте всё чаще замечаю использование вместо "Добрый день!" формулировки с более явным пожеланием "Доброго дня!", иногда развернутую до "Всем доброго дня!" (при обращении к группе людей) или "Доброго дня вам!" (при обращении к одному человеку). Эти же формулировки я вижу иногда и в качестве прощания, но значительно реже.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!